# How to find dim($X \cap Y$) and dim($X + Y$)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $X=\{p \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4 : p(1+i)=0\}$, $Y=\{q \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4 : aq(1-i)=(1-a)q(0) \}$. I need to find dim($X \cap Y$) and dim($X + Y$) depending on $a$.

Also let $ux^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ a polynomial. For $X$ we have $$-4u+(-2+2i)b + 2ic+(1+i)d+e=0$$ so $-4u-2b+d+e=0$ and $2b+2c+d=0$. For $Y$ we have $$a(-4u+(-2-2i)b+(-2i)c+(1-i)d+e) = (1-a)e$$ How to finish it?

Answer (score 0):

SKETCH OF THE SOLUTION: let $p\in\Bbb R[x]_4$. Then if $\lambda$ is a non-real root of $p$ then it is also $\bar\lambda$. Hence for $p\in X$ we knows that $p(1+i)=0$ if and only if $p(1-i)=0$. Thus if $p\in X$ it have the form $p(x)=(x-1+i)(x+1-i)r(x)$ for some $r\in\Bbb R[x]_2$.

Therefore $\dim X=3$.

Now, if $a\neq 0$ we have that if $q\in Y$ then $q(1-i)=q(0)\frac{1-a}a$. Thus $q(1-i)=0$ if and only if $q(0)=0$ or $a=1$. So you can go case by case to see what is $Y$ depending if $a=1$, $a=0$ or a different choice. After you can conclude what is $X\cap Y$ or $X+Y$ in each case.